# ORACLE SQL - Using a SUM in a WHERE clause with a GROUP BY invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query in ORACLE SQL where i need to return results only if the SUM of the debet_amount's OR the credit_amount's are greater than or equal too 1000 per v_no.

**Current Error**

```
ORA-00904: "g"."COMPANY": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

**Current Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
g.company,
g.v_type,
g.v_no,
g.v_date,
g.a_year,
g.a_period, 
g.entry_date,
g.correction,
CASE WHEN g.mcompany IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE g.mcompany END AS mcompany,
g.debet_amount,
g.credit_amount,
g.amount,
v.userid
FROM genrow g, 
(SELECT v_no, SUM(debet_amount) AS debcomp FROM genrow GROUP BY v_no) subdeb,
(SELECT v_no, SUM(credit_amount) AS credcomp FROM genrow GROUP BY v_no) subcred
INNER JOIN genv v ON g.v_no = v.v_no AND g.company = v.company
WHERE g.v_no = subdeb.v_no
AND g.v_no = subcred.v_no
AND (subdeb.debcomp >= 1000 or subcred.credcomp >= 1000)
AND g.v_type IN ('M','Q','E')
```

**Example Expected Output**

```
company v_type  v_no    v_date          a_year  a_period    entry_date  correction  mcompnay    debet_amount    credit_amount   amount  userid
02      EXT     2000    25-JAN-14       2014    1           28-JAN-14   N           FALSE       600                             600     USER13
02      EXT     2000    25-JAN-14       2014    1           28-JAN-14   N           FALSE       200                             200     USER16
02      EXT     2000    25-JAN-14       2014    1           28-JAN-14   N           FALSE       300                             300     USER12
02      EXT     4000    25-JAN-14       2014    1           28-JAN-14   N           FALSE                       500             500     USER19
02      M       4000    29-MAR-14       2014    3           07-APR-14   N           FALSE                       200             200     USER12
02      EXT     4000    25-JAN-14       2014    1           28-JAN-14   N           FALSE                       120             120     USER18
02      EXT     4000    25-JAN-14       2014    1           28-JAN-14   N           FALSE                       700             700     USER14
02      EXT     6000    25-JAN-14       2014    1           28-JAN-14   N           FALSE       1100                            1100    USER19
```

Comment: Looks like 'genrow' table doesn't contain 'mcompany' column. Does it?

Comment: Yes, it does contain it

Comment: `AND (subdeb.debcomp >= 1000 or subcred.credcomp >= 1000)` can be moved into the subselects as part of a `HAVING` clause, which may improve performance some (and definitely makes it easier to read).

Comment: Using the answer below how would i implement `HAVING` into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing implicit and explicit joins which cannot be parsed properly.

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    g.company,
    g.v_type,
    g.v_no,
    g.v_date,
    g.a_year,
    g.a_period, 
    g.entry_date,
    g.correction,
    CASE WHEN g.mcompany IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE g.mcompany END AS mcompany,
    g.debet_amount,
    g.credit_amount,
    g.amount,
    v.userid
FROM genrow g
INNER JOIN (SELECT v_no, SUM(debet_amount) AS debcomp FROM genrow GROUP BY v_no) subdeb ON g.v_no = subdeb.v_no
INNER JOIN (SELECT v_no, SUM(credit_amount) AS credcomp FROM genrow GROUP BY v_no) subcred ON g.v_no = subcred.v_no
INNER JOIN genv v ON g.v_no = v.v_no AND g.company = v.company
WHERE (subdeb.debcomp >= 1000 or subcred.credcomp >= 1000)
AND g.v_type IN ('M','Q','E');
```

Comment: Works a charm :) Thank You Thorsten!